# Regex: Returning all groups with separator in regex definition

Tags: regex

I am posting this question because I have been looking for it for a few hours now without any chance.

I would like to recognize a comma separated list of items, with the possiblity that some items contain a comma themselves.

i.e. parse this:

```
foo CHAR (10) "NVL(:D_1, ' ')", bar CHAR ( 25 )
```

and find the following groups: (using [this tool](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html))

```
0: [0,14] foo CHAR (10) "NVL(:D_1, ' ')"
1: [0,3] foo
2: [4,13] CHAR (10)
3: [10,12] 10
4: [14,14] "NVL(:D_1, ' ')"
```

for the moment, using the below regex:

```
(?:|\G(?!^),)(\w+)\s(CHAR\s*\(\s*(\d+)\s*\)|TIMESTAMP\s*\"YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF\")\s*((?:\"NVL\(\w*\,\s* \' \'\)\"){0,1})
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

I only manage to find (the {0,1} cardinality is read 0):

```
0: [0,14] foo CHAR (10) 
1: [0,3] foo
2: [4,13] CHAR (10)
3: [10,12] 10
4: [14,14]
```

I thank you in advance for your time and suggestions.

SOLUTION:

```
(?:|\G(?!^),)(\w+)\s(CHAR\s*\(\s*(\d+)\s*\)|TIMESTAMP\s*\"YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF\")\s*(\"NVL\(:?\w*\,\s* \' \'\)\")?
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: You seem to have rather random seperators, could you explain it a bit more detailed? Why for example does it split more than once, as all you have mentioned so far is that it should split on commas that are not part of a word, and the only one I see is the one after `' ')"`...

Comment: @Voidpaw: As far as I understand, `\G(?!^),` defines the split. I would like it to be split after `"NVL(:D_1, ' ')"` and not after `:D_1`

Comment: http://fiddle.re/14mye
is that the result you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have nothing to match the `:` in `NVG(:D_1`

Try:

```
(?:|\G(?!^),)(\w+)\s(CHAR\s*\(\s*(\d+)\s*\)|TIMESTAMP\s*\"YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF\")\s*((\"NVL\(:?\w*\,\s* \' \'\)\")?)
```

[Working in RegexPal](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=%28?%3a%7C%5CG%28?!%5E%29,%29%28%5Cw%2b%29%5Cs%28CHAR%5Cs%2a%5C%28%5Cs%2a%28%5Cd%2b%29%5Cs%2a%5C%29%7CTIMESTAMP%5Cs%2a%5C%22YYYY-MM-DD%20HH24%3aMI%3aSS.FF%5C%22%29%5Cs%2a%28%28%5C%22NVL%5C%28%3a?%5Cw%2a%5C,%5Cs%2a%20%5C%27%20%5C%27%5C%29%5C%22%29?%29&input=foo%20CHAR%20%2810%29%20%22NVL%28%3aD_1,%20%27%20%27%29%22,%20bar%20CHAR%20%28%2025%20%29)

I've just put in a `:?` but I have no idea what your requirements are.

Comment: Thanks a lot @OGHaza : this was it. I updated my question with the solution (small group change). Have a nice day

Comment: @jhoelter no problemo